# Is it possible to tune atlassian-sdk to not display the [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] prefix in the console messages?

Tags: maven, tomcat, atlassian-plugin-sdk

While using `atlas-run` (customized maven) from atlassian-plugin-sdk you will see the application output prefixed by `[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]`, like below:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 6.x starting...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Nov 22, 2012 4:17:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/sorins/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
```

This interferes with my terminal which is configured the highlight errors and warnings (based on regexp) and I want to find a way of running this without having the see the not-so-useful prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-q` option to turn off `[INFO]` lines in Maven.

Otherwise, you could try piping the command through something like this...

```
sed "s/\[INFO\] \[talledLocalContainer\] //"
```